# Change wordpress permalink structure for posts in a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

Currently my permalink structure is `/%postname%` and I'm trying to change the permalink structure specifically for the posts in the category 'Information'. So when users click on an post within that category the url will show `/category/postname/` and an exmaple would be something like this: `/information/guide`
Rather then just `/guide`

But I still want every other post outside of the 'Information' category to just have the permalink structure of `/%postname%/`

Would I have to use the WP_Rewrite class? How do I use it?

Comment: Add this `/%category%/%postname%/` to your permalink structure.

Comment: If you read my post I said it needs to be posts within **one specific category** while keeping just /%postname*/ for other posts. Doing what you suggest would have the category before every post. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried this [**Advanced Permalinks**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-permalinks/screenshots/) plugin

Comment: Yes I tried it but it doesn't work. =/ looks like the plugin is out of date